# How to use query param import in webpack with typescript without getting Cannot find module?

Tags: typescript, webpack, responsive-loader

```
import a from 'a.png?sizes[]=64'
```

but I get a ts error `Cannot find module 'a.png?sizes[]=64'`. All works with webpack, but tsc check types fails because there is no file like that. That should only check for `a.png` with query param.

Any ideas how to do that? I run this command to check types `tsc --project ./tsconfig.json --noEmit`

One hack is to use `require()` syntax but that will skip any checks. So even if the file is missing, no error will happen.

Comment: have you tried the following https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#wildcard-module-declarations
```ts
declare module "*.png?*" {
  const path: string;
  export default path;
}
```

Comment: @AlexanderAlexandrov That gives an error `Pattern "*.png?*" can have at most one '*' character`

Answer (score 4):

Adding additional declaration helped, but there must be a better way.

e.g. `types/import-png.d.ts`

```
declare module '*.png' {
  const value: string;

  export default value;
}

declare module '*.png?inline' {
  const value: string;

  export default value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by adding an extra parameter to the url and matching on it.

```js
declare module '*&useResponsiveLoader=true' {
    const defaultExport: {
        srcSet: string,
        images: {
            height: number;
            width: number;
            path: string;
        }[],
        src: string,
        placeholder: string,
        toString(): string
    };
    export default defaultExport;
}
```

This works because responsive loader does allow unused properties according to its validation schema (both the current and next versions)

You then import the file as

```js
import a from 'a.png?sizes[]=64&useResponsiveLoader=true'
import b from 'b.png?sizes[]=64,sizes[]=128&useResponsiveLoader=true'
```

(Note that responsive loader 5 requires more tweaks to get working with Webpack 5, I'm still figuring these out)